# jQuery plugins scrollTo and scrollLocal not working on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

**I'm using the following jQuery plugins (along with the jQuery plugin):**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.localscroll-min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/custom.js"></script>
```

When I click this anchor link:

```
<a href="#contact">Contact me today!</a></p>
```

It scrolls smoothly to my:

```
<div id="contact">
```

**custom.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //smooth scrolling for all anchor links.
        $.localScroll({ speed: 2000, });
    });
```

It works in Firefox and Chrome but it doesn't work on IE. It just goes to #contact but not using the scrollTo or scrollLocal plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure about this `,` after `speed: 2000`?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //smooth scrolling for all anchor links.
    $.localScroll({ speed: 2000, });
});
```

Comment: Good catch. IE doesn't like those trailing commas in object literals